# double click difficulty: mouse drag / move / shift between first and second click, what can i do?

Tags: windows-10, mouse, double-click

I observe that the mouse pointer often moves like 1 or 2 pixels during my first press of my double-clicking, which then sometimes registers as a very small drag.

Can I somehow get the mouse to interpret a 1 pixel drag during the first "click" as part of a double click?

Context: I believe it is a consequence of the fact that I started using multi-monitor setups with large screen resolutions. My mouse speed and sensitivity needs to be set quite high in order to be able to navigate that screen estate.

Comment: You probably need a low initial speed with high acceleration to provide stability at low speed, & 'zippiness' across the screen area at high speed. idk how to do that on Windows, but it ought to be a start-point for you. It's something I've used on Mac for years, across 2 large screens; a flick takes you right across, but a slow drag has precision.

Comment: Hm yes, that caused me to again take a close look at the windows mouse options, where I found the option "Enhance pointer precision". Please convert to an answer, and i will add the screenshot.

Comment: I believe "acceleration" is already part of the "pointer speed" setting in windows, but I could be wrong.

Comment: As you have found the answer yourself, even if using hints from my comment - please feel free to add your own answer, with pics if appropriate, & mark is as accepted if it works for you. [Self Q&A is perfectly acceptable, even encouraged, at SE]

Comment: I know, just wanted to give you the credit.

Comment: No worries at all. I don't really need the rep points. I'm just happy you found your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I upgraded to a high-DPI gaming mouse. There are two setting in the Windows Registry that might help: DoubleClickWidth and DoubleClickHeight.

They set how far a double-click may roam between clicks specified in pixeks. My defaults were 4. I changed them both to 25. You may want to go even higher.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I went back to a lower resolution screen, but will keep this in mind for the future. Will accept untested.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the option "Enhance pointer precision" stabilizes my mouse during clicks.

[image]